# Any way to switch to quirks mode on IE6/7?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, quirks-mode

IE6/7 don't support "box-sizing: border-box" but they render all boxes as a "border-box" on quirks mode.
And I need a css grid(like in bootstrap.css) based on the border-box model which can run in 6/7.

Could any one tell a way to switch to quirks mode ONLY on IE6/7 (doesn't affect IE8 or higher)? Thanks!

Comment: Quirks mode isn't just there for you to use the border-box model. I don't think half of Bootstrap would even *work* correctly in IE in quirks mode.

Comment: Nobody uses ie6/7 anymore... IE11 is out...

Comment: @MarsOne: believe it or not, there are still workplaces out there that mandate IE6 support - I know of one website for a bank which still supports IE4!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Its safe to say i would never invest in that bank ;-) WHy should we continue to find a work around for browsers that Microsoft themselves wont support... A huge number of ppl still use WindowsXP. But Micosoft will stop supporting it by next April... Why? Cause its just bad business... Simple. ;)

Comment: My first recommendation would be to drop support for IE6/7 as soon as you can (or if you can't, make sure you're getting paid well for this project; I know devs who add an extra zero to their prices if the spec includes IE6).

Answer (score 0):

Dont provide a doctype and they should switch into quirks mode - if you make it conditional you can screen out those browsers you don't want targeted.

That said, I would strongly recommend you look for a solution which doesn't require this approach.

I'd also recommend giving [this article a read](http://hsivonen.fi/doctype/), as well as [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)

*Quote:*

> Old pages written before (or in spite of) the standardization wave
>   don’t have a doctype. Therefore ’no doctype’ would mean quirks mode:
>   show according to old rules.
>
> Contrarily, if the web developer was savvy enough to include a
>   doctype, he probably knew what he was doing. Therefore most doctypes
>   trigger strict mode: show according to pure standards.
>
> Any new or unknown doctype triggers strict mode.
>
> The problem was that some pages written in quirks mode did have
>   doctypes. Therefore each browser has its own list with doctypes that
>   trigger quirks mode.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this alternative would work because IE doesn't understand `X-UA-Compatible` until version 8.

Comment: @BoltClock correct as ever :) I've edited to remove the offending note. +1

Answer (score 0):

Please don't think that Quirks mode is a viable solution here. It does a lot more than simply changing the box model. It switches off a whole range of browser features, and has a number of other changes to rendering as well. It will also make it incredibly difficult to make your site work accurately across different browsers, particularly since we're talking about older IE's here.

My suggested alternative would be to use a polyfill for the `border-box` feature. There are a number of them available, and they would allow you to use `border-box` as regular CSS even in IE6. You can find a [list of several of them here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#basic-user-interface-spec). Try them out, and pick one that works for you. Problem solved.

Note: I have to be honest here: I've never actually had any need to use these polyfills, but if they're listed on Modernizr's polyfill list, it's probably a pretty safe to say they do the job.